# vb.net - How to use Textboxes and ComboBoxes from Treeview

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox, treeview

I am looking for some sample code that shows how to use `Textboxes` and `ComboBoxes` from a `Treeview` control.

I want the `Textboxes` and `ComboBoxes` to be inline with label text.

This graphic shows what I have in mind:

[image]

Comment: I'm not convinced that's a good GUI. I think using a complex-type and the WinForms `PropertyGrid` control would be better. The `PropertyGrid` control supports nested objects so you can get a treeview-esque behaviour that way, without having to actually implement anything.

Comment: Thanks, Dai. Can you point me to an example of how to use the WinForms PropertyGrid control with nested objects?  Thanks, Leigh